# How to write this sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have these Attributes in a table ABC

Location, Zone, Sector, UnitNo

and want to write a query for them where Location and UnitNo are same but Sector is different
means I have sectors in different locations where UnitNo is same

I wrote this one but does not work.

```
select * from ABC A1 Inner JOIN ABC A2 on A1.Id = A2.ID
WHERE 
A1.Sector <> A2.Sector AND A1.Location = A2.Location ANd A1.UnitNo = A2.UnitNo
```

please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
select location, unitno
from abc
group by location, unitno
having count(distinct sector) > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT DISTINCT Sector from ABC where location = unitno;

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you needed the following query

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    YourTable
WHERE 
    Location=UnitNo AND 
    Location<>Sector
```

Comment: ...there is no comparison between location, sector, unitno ... there are different attributes

Comment: @Azhar Please add some sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Please fine the below code

```
select * from ABC A1 Inner JOIN ABC A2 
on A1.Id = A2.ID
and A1.Sector <> A2.Sector 
AND A1.Location = A2.Location 
ANd A1.UnitNo = A2.UnitNo
```

Comment: when you are using inner join keyword WHERE clause is not working.
you have to use ON claluse.